# Why are there two different Ubuntu Software apps?

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

I came across the *Ubuntu Software Center* application while I was looking through Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 16.04. It had the same icon and a lot of the same apps as the Software app. Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Ubuntu 16.04 the Ubuntu Software Center app was the primary graphical tool for installing software from package repositories on a system running Ubuntu linux.

However, Starting in 16.04 the Ubuntu Software Center was replaced by Ubuntu Software which is based off of Gnome Software.

Answer (score 0):

The classical Ubuntu Software Center (USC) was too old, too slow and practically obsolete. Canonical switched to (GNOME) Software app since 16.04 for being faster and easier on hardware resources.